# How to insert a document with a subdocument array element in MongoDB with Monk

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, subdocument, monk

when i want to insert a document in my mongodb with monk wich has an array element of subdocuments, the funcion insert it wrong in the db.
I'm calling the insert function this way:

```
var OrderItem = [];
OrderItem[0] = {
                'model': asd1,
                'size' : M,
                'color' : Black
            };

OrderItem[1] = {
                'model': bsa2,
                'size' : S,
                'color' : Black
            };
var newOrdenCompra = {
            'fechaCompra' : d,
            'items' : OrderItem
        };
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: newOrdenCompra,
        url: '/order/addordercompra',
        dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function( response ) 
        {
            if (response.msg !== '') {
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
            }
        });
```

and then:

```
/*
 * POST to add orden de compra.
 */
router.post('/addordercompra', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('ordercompra');
    collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

But what i get into the BD is something like this (the example that i wrote above have less atributes in the item subdocuments):

```
> db.ordercompra.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5601b2181430470c1266d415"),
        "fechaCompra" : "2015-09-22T16:54:59Z",
        "items[0][model]" : "CLUB DE LA PELEA",
        "items[0][size]" : "XXXS",
        "items[0][color]" : "CHOCOLATE",
        "items[0][sena]" : "1200",
        "items[0][precio]" : "2600",
        "items[0][ordOT]" : "2",
        "items[0][id]" : "55f9e402ebfcd9b414339f8f",
        "items[1][model]" : "302",
        "items[1][size]" : "M",
        "items[1][color]" : "NEGRO",
        "items[1][sena]" : "0",
        "items[1][precio]" : "2100",
        "items[1][ordOT]" : "",
        "items[1][id]" : "55e76c0d497c742019bbb5f3"
}
>
```

What can i do to get the structure of an element with an array of subdocuments? am i doing it wrong or is the insert what's failing?

Thanks for the help! and sorry for my bad english.
Nicolas.

Comment: You should probably JSON.stringify(data) on client and then JSON.parse(req.body) on server

Comment: Hi!, thanks for help!, i can send the JSON.stringifu(newOrdenCompra) to the server, but when i test it, if i parse the req.body, then the function crashes. And if i don't parse it, the function just save a string with all the data. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Also your $.ajax dataType should be "application/json; charset=utf-8" rather then JSON  what do you mean by "the function crashes". Anyway I think you should insert only fechaCompra without items and than result.items =[] and in a loop  result.items.push(items[i]) and than result.save()

Comment: Thanks for the help Molda!, but i solved the problem changing the dataType to 'text' and adding contentType as 'application/json', doing that i didn't need to parse the req.body, i'd just send req.body to the insert function and it worked. – And with Crashes i mean that the parse function throws an 'Unexpected token o' error, beacause the object req.body is already an object.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem sending the data transformed with JSON.stringify and changed the ajax parameters to dataType : 'text' and adding contentType: 'application/json'. Doing that the insert works perfect.
Thanks for the help!
Example Imgs:

[image: client code]

[image: server code]

And the BD looks like this:

[image: bd data]